# A page should be opened only in a window

Tags: php, javascript

I have a small application in PHP in which when a button (`type='button'` and not `type='submit'`) is clicked, a new window is opened and a page is loaded into that window. Some insertion operations into the database are performed on that page on the window using Ajax.

The page which is loaded into the window should only be opened in a window. If the URL of that page is entered directly into the address bar of the web browser, the page must be protected and redirected to some other page, it may be a home page of the application. I tried using `window.opener.closed` but it doesn't suit this requirement.

In PHP, I can check

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET")
{
    header("location:Home.php");
}
```

But that will also redirect the page in the window to the Home.php page because I'm using Ajax on the `GET` request on that page.

Is there a way to determine if a page can only be loaded into a window? In all cases, it must be prevented from being loaded.

Thanks.

Comment: This cannot be done on the PHP side at all .. PHP has no way of knowing if there was a `window.opener` available.  You can open the new window and then load the page with JS if `window.opener` is available .. otherwise redirect, but you can't do that on the server side.

Comment: Don't do that. Whoever will use your page - he won't like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check if the opener attribute was set if you opened that protected adress in a regular browser adress bar? If not then you could check it on loading the window, and exit whenever this value is unset

Comment: I think this is an acceptable check, since in your own app you can decide whether or not the adress bars are editable in window.open

Comment: I did that using jQuery function something like this `jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  if(window.opener==null)
  {
   window.location="index.php"; 
  }
    });`. May be conceptually wrong but it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a secret key via the $_GET to the popup. If the key is not valid you would perform the redirect away from the page. This means a user who accessed the page directly would not know the secret key.

Remember to also put an exit after your header redirect otherwise the script may continue processing!